# Definition and (non) equivalent definition of f being continuous

Tags: continuity, definition

so I am preparing for my final and I needed some help verifying my definitions and their justifications. So any help/feedback would be appreciated...

Let $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a given function, and f is continuous. Then out of the following defnition pick the right definition, and/or equuivalent definition. If the definition is not equivalent provide explanation:

a.) for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x \in (0,1)$ and $0 \lt |x-x_0| \lt \delta$, one has $|f(x) - f(x_0)|\lt \epsilon$.

this definition is true.

b.) for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x \in (0,1)$ and $|x-x_0| \leq \delta$, one has $|f(x) - f(x_0)|\leq \epsilon$.

this definition is equivalent.

c.) for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, for any $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x \in (0,1)$ and $ |x-x_0| \lt \delta$, one has $|f(x) - f(x_0)|\lt \epsilon$.

this definition is false because for any ϵ>0 there exists some δ>0 that is small enough. It can't be any delta.

d.) for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $x \in (0,1)$ and $0 \lt |x-x_0| \lt \delta$, one has $0 \lt |f(x) - f(x_0)|\leq \epsilon$.

this definition is false. I dont quite know how to provide an explanation for it tho.

these are my attempts on the identification. Could you please help me confirm these answers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d) is not true for a constant function $f$, since we then get $|f(x) - f(x_0)| = 0$. But $f$ is continuous.

Comment: am i right for a)-c)??

Answer (score 0):

For **a)** a counter-example

$f(x)=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{l}0 \quad \text{if}\;x=\frac{1}{2}\\x\quad \text{if}\;x\in (0,1)\backslash\{\frac{1}{2}\}\end{array}\right.$